# How do I insert a picture to cover the whole background of a single page only? This is what happened with the code

Tags: backgrounds

[image]I want to insert a logo for a single page. The logo should cover the whole page size. How do I do it?

Comment: eso-pic package might help

Comment: How do I use it?

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

with the eso-pic package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}


\begin{document}


\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image}}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

with the tikz package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

---

Edit: to place the image NOT in the background but on a page of its own:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\clearpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

or with pdfpages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\includepdf[height=\paperheight]{example-image}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: there is an additional text also that appeared with the picture. How do i remove it

Comment: @NirashanPradhan Huh, which text do you mean?

Comment: see my edit above

Comment: @NirashanPradhan So you don't want it in the background but as a standalone page?

Comment: I want it in a single page only

Comment: @NirashanPradhan I added two more solutions for not placing it in the backgroud. is this what you want?

Comment: I want it as abackground to be able to write above it

Comment: @NirashanPradhan Sorry, I have to give up. I have no idea what you are asking

Comment: I want the image as the background of the page and texts to be written above it.